# CVXPY DCPError for Convex Function

Tags: cvxpy

I have a convex optimization problem I am trying to solve with cvxpy.  Given a `1 x n` row vector `y` and an `m x n` matrix `C`, I want to find a scalar `b` and a `1 x m` row vector `a` such that the sum of squares of `y - (aC + b(aC @ aC))` is as small as possible (the `@` denotes element wise multiplication).  In addition, all entires in `a` must be nonnegative and sum to 1 and `-100 <= b <= 100`.  Below is my attempt to solve this using cvxpy.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx

def find_a(y, C, b_min=-100, b_max=100):
    b = cvx.Variable()
    a = cvx.Variable( (1,C.shape[0]) )

    aC = a * C # this should be matrix multiplication
    x = (aC + cvx.multiply(b, cvx.square(aC)))

    objective = cvx.Minimize ( cvx.sum_squares(y - x) )

    constraints = [0. <= a,
                   a <= 1.,
                   b_min <= b,
                   b <= b_max,
                   cvx.sum(a) == 1.]

    prob = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)
    result = prob.solve()

    print a.value
    print result

y = np.asarray([[0.10394265, 0.25867508, 0.31258457, 0.36452763, 0.36608997]])

C = np.asarray([
     [0.,         0.00169811, 0.01679245, 0.04075472, 0.03773585],
     [0.,         0.00892802, 0.03154158, 0.06091544, 0.07315024],
     [0.,         0.00962264, 0.03245283, 0.06245283, 0.07283019],
     [0.04396226, 0.05245283, 0.12245283, 0.18358491, 0.23886792]])

find_a(y, C)
```

I keep getting a `DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules.` error when I try to solve for `a`.  I am thinking that either my function is not really convex, or I do not understand how to construct the proper cvxpy `Problem`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `aC @ aC` is quadratic. `b(aC @ aC)` is cubic. When you then take the squared 2-norm, you obtain a polynomial function of degree 6.